# Como editar a scrollbar no Firefox e Google Chrone

Tags: css

Ola tenho esse código de CSS que configura a barra de rolagem no site com tudo não funciona no Firefox e nem no Google Chrone alguém poderia me ajudar segue abaixo o código.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:2px;
    height:10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    background:#000000;
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    background:#000000;

}
```

Esse codigo CSS funcionou perfeitamente no no Navegador Opera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estilizar a barra de rolagem não é um recurso especificado nas CSS, não é um padrão. Ainda assim muitos usuários e desenvolvedores solicitam que esta (e outras) *feature* seja implementada nos demais navegadores por meio dos canais de comunicação de cada um.

Navegadores com motor *webkit* já permitem essa estilização da *scrollbar*, bem como [o Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a partir da versão 9. Já o Firefox... bem... existe [um tópico no **BugZilla** sobre o assunto](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790) há 14 anos.

Como este <s>ainda</s> não é um recurso [*cross-browser*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser) a melhor opção é optar por utilizar algum *plugin* que permita a estilização e trate a diferença entre navegadores.

---

[Nesta página](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/scrollbar/) há uma seleção com alguns, como:

- [**Perfect Scrollbar**](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) - <kbd>[**DEMO**](https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar)</kbd>
- [**Scroller**](https://github.com/FormstoneClassic/Scroller) - <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://formstone.it/components/scrollbar/#demo)</kbd>
- [**SlimScroll**](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll) - <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/)</kbd>
- [**jScrollPane**](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) - <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html)</kbd>

---

Formas de alterar o *scroll* padrão do navegador utilizando o *Perfect Scrollbar* (que dos listados acima foi o que achei mais interessante):

#### Exemplo [aplicando scroll na página toda]

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').perfectScrollbar();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.classQueForcaOScroll {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- JS do plugin -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.5.9/perfect-scrollbar.min.js'></script>

<!-- CSS do plugin -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.5.9/perfect-scrollbar.min.css'>

 <!-- div só para forçar o scroll da página -->
<div class='classQueForcaOScroll'></div>
```

#### Exemplo [aplicando scroll em um elemento específico]

```js
$(function(){
  $('.foo').perfectScrollbar();
});
```

```css
.foo {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60px;  
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.5.9/perfect-scrollbar.min.js'></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.5.9/perfect-scrollbar.min.css'>

<div class='foo'>
  scroll scroll scroll scroll<br>
  scroll scroll scroll scroll<br>
  scroll scroll scroll scroll<br>
  scroll scroll scroll scroll<br>
  scroll scroll scroll scroll<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Grato pela ajuda era isso mesmo que eu queria.

Comment: @Rodrigo De textarea eu não sei, só lendo a documentação para saber. Em div é possível sim, acabei de incluir um segundo exemplo aplicando o scroll nele.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.